# string manipulation in regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string

i have a problem in string manipulation

here is the code

```
string str = "LDAP://company.com/OU=MyOU1 Control,DC=MyCompany,DC=com";
Regex regex = new Regex("OU=\\w+");
var result = regex.Matches(str);
var strList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    strList.Add(item.ToString().Remove(0,3));
 }
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join("/",strList));
```

the result i am getting is "MyOU1" instead of getting "MyOU1 Control"

please help thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the space character to be matched as well, you need to include it in your regex. `\w` only matches word charactes, which does not include spaces.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"OU=[\w\s]+");
```

This matches word characters (`\w`) and whitespace characters (`\s`).

(The `@` in front of the string is just for convenience: If you use it, you don't need to escape backslashes.)

Comment: For future reference, @-prefixed strings go by the name of *verbatim strings*.

Answer (score 4):

Either add space to the allowed list (\w doesn't allow space) or use the knowledge that comma can be used as a separator.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("OU=(\\w|\\s)+");
```

OR

```
Regex regex = new Regex("OU=[^,]+");
```